# Error in build XCODE 6.4 - linker command failed

Tags: ios, linker-errors

Next error appears on attempt to build. Can someone help me? I sought the forum, but nothing worked.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/..'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/..'
ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you include GoogleAnalyticsServices in your Build Rules?

Comment: yes, have other idea ?

Comment: Remove it and add it again. In the event that you configured multiple targets, make sure that you include it for each target that requires it.

Comment: Can you please add an image of your Framework search paths, Header search paths, and Library search paths.

Comment: Hermann Thank you! :)